# Long property as foreign key in JPA entity

Tags: java, jpa, foreign-keys

Im having two tables Review and Bedrijfsgegevens. The Review table has a primary key (reviewId) and a foreign key (bedrijfId). BedrijfId is a primary key (as Id) in Bedrijfsgegevens table. I faced this problem because I was trying to add a row in Review table with an bedrijfId that did not exists in the Bedrijfgegevens table and rightfully got an Exception.

I tried to use I used @ManyToOne and @JoinColumn annotations to prevent gettings this Exception. However, nonethelss I get an Exception saying "IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field org.loepr.loeprservices.models.Bedrijfsgegevens.id to java.lang.Long"

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "bedrijfreviews")
public class Review {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bedrijfsgegevens.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bedrijfid")
    private Long bedrijfId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("reviewId")
    @Column(name = "reviewid")
    private Long reviewId;

    //other properties
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Bedrijfsgegevens {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private Long id;

    //other properties
}
```

I expect to create a relationship between primary and foreign key in JPA entities so that when I use a bedrijfId (foreign key) that does not exists as primary key in Bedrijfgegevens table I do not get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The field `Review.bedrijfId` should be declared a `Bedrijfsgegevens`; e.g.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "bedrijfreviews")
public class Review {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bedrijfsgegevens.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bedrijfid")
    private Bedrijfsgegevens bedrijf;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("reviewId")
    @Column(name = "reviewid")
    private Long reviewId;

    //other properties
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for your answer. I tried this before and I faced two issues. Firstly, if I add a non-existing bedrijfid, it throws a javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException which does not solve the issue of my application tidely dealing with this situation. Secondly, now the request in the controller expects a complete Bedrijfsgegevens object where I only want to include the bedrijfId field of the Bedrijfsgegevens object. How do I solve these issues?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing when you receive the EntityNotFoundException. I would need some more detail. But, if you really want to have only the bedrijfId value, you can use a simple Basic mapping as you do not need the ManyToOne mapping. You will then need to fetch the target object manually.

Comment: What if you only want the it and not all the other properties? There has to be a way of just specifying the primary key